# Scrolling top to bottom using UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am looking for an example that show just vertical scrolling in iPhone.

- The Apple supplied Scrolling example allows swiping of images left to
  right.

  1. [Example Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html)
  2. [Example Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html)
- I want to have my images scroll `top to bottom` like [Instagram
  App](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=821f5Bic294&feature=related).
- I research about it and found lots of example, but they all show
  horizontal scrolling.

  1. [Example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content)
  2. [Example](http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/)
  3. [Example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html)

**Does anyone know how to do this?**

I appreciate if you send me a link to a tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i solved your problem with apple code,

just change the function with

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
    UIImageView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

    // reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
    CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin = CGPointMake(0,curXLoc);
            view.frame = frame;

            curXLoc += (kScrollObjHeight);
        }
    }

    // set the content size so it can be scrollable
    [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(([scrollView1 bounds].size.width),kNumImages * kScrollObjHeight)];
}
```

or if you want sample then i will give you

Comment: Yes it works fine, but I tried it for my own app. I got a problem.can you please check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538776/vertical-images-in-uiscrollview

Comment: that is new question..this question is about vertical scrolling..i will check your problem, but in this section you have to accept answer...

Comment: Yes of course, I need to ckeck all the answers and then choose the most useful one. I'll to that. +1 for your help untill now ;)

Comment: This question is all about vertical scrolling and the requirement of this question is fulfill ... so first accept the most useful answer and then i will give you solution of your problem of that question..:)

Comment: @Rajneesh071, thanks man, you should be patient, I needed to check all answers. By the way please send me your sample that you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose refer your link:

http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/

There is a code like:

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

For horizontal scrolling you need to set the `width` of `contentSize` property to a higher value than the scroll view's f`rame width`. Likewise for vertical scrolling you need to set the `height` of `contentSize` property to a higher value than the scroll view's `frame height`.

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

In the above code it can be done like:

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, numberOfViews * self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but I faced with a problem that I couldn't solve, look at this please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538776/vertical-images-in-uiscrollview

Comment: I still could not find any tutorial that show vertical scrolling like instagram App(you can check it out in the link).

Comment: @Ali: I answered to that question. please check that

Comment: TI appreciate for the help. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to scroll images from top to bottom and vice versa.!!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//....
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
//for scrolling up
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeUp)]; // calling method SwipeUp
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];


  //for scrolling down  
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer1;
    recognizer1 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeDown)]; //calling method SwipeDown
    [recognizer1 setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer1];

}
```

//Initialise and synthesise  `IBOutlet UIImageView *bgImage;`

```
-(IBAction)SwipeUp
{


        [bgImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage1"] ];

          bgImage.opaque=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:bgImage];
}


-(IBAction)SwipeDown
{


        [bgImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage2"] ];

        bgImage.opaque=YES;
    [self.view addSubview:bgImage];
}
```

Comment: I used gestures to scroll .!!

Comment: you can use a scroll view also. just add your view as a sub view . !!

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538776/vertical-images-in-uiscrollview. I got this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly what you want to accomplish but basically you can set the position of you scrollView using setContentOffset.

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
[scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

Comment: Take a look at Instagram App. You can move between images vertically. Look at my link, and let me know if you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

*There are several ways of doing this for example:*

1. Using the UITableView with Custom cell
2. Adding UIScrollingView & adding the content/images & increasing the
   height of scrollview according to number of objects in array.

**Here is the code snippet which creates a 2*2 Grid for images :**

```
//Over here adding the image names into the Array
NSMutableArray *imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [Arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_1.png"]];
    [Arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_2.png"]];
    [Arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_3.png"]];
    [Arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_4.png"]];
    [Arr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_5.png"]];
```

**// Initlaizing the ScrollView & setting the frame :**

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 460)];
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++) {

    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(column*160+0,row*210+10, 160, 190);
    [button setImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(chooseCustomImageTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = i; 
    [view1 addSubview:button];

    if (column == 1) {
        column = 0;
        row++;
    } else {
        column++;
    }

}

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, (row+1) * 210)];

[self.view addSubview:view1];
```

**//Here is the method used for Tapping :**

```
- (IBAction)chooseCustomImageTapped:(id)sender
{

}
```

Now,once the scrollView is ready for Vertical scrolling, you can do your own customization accordingly. I hope this would work for you.